# Is it possible to forward a page from a private server to the client through a public server

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

If I'm asking something stupid, please forgive my ignorance.

Following is an example to clarify the question:

1. I got a public Flask server that opens to the public (Server 1).
2. I also got another private web server, which based on Flask as well (Server 2). 
   (let's assume I cannot integrate this server with my Flask server)
3. Now I have a client have access to the public server, wants to get one page on the private server.

Is this possible?

Like, when Server 1 receive a request from the Client, Server 1 will go to Server 2 and fetch the page, then give it back to the Client?

Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: You can if you set up a tunnel for accessing your private server. A service like ngrok could help you here.

Comment: The word you're looking for is *flask proxy server*.

Comment: @mx0 Thanks man! I found a code snippet http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/118/. But it seems it cannot give the pictures, javascripts, etc. back. Any suggestion?